# Print specific number from string via AWK/SED

Tags: awk, sed

I have large file from which I need to extract specific value. I am looking for the string with "Brontes" word in it and for the time of the service start.

```
2016-09-05 11:23:08,022 ERROR [xxx.xxx.xx] (MSC service thread 1-6) XXXX015875: XXXX AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 275637ms - Started 1221 of 1307 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 71 services are passive or on-demand)
```

I was trying to print this like that:

```
awk '/Brontes/{print $18}' file
```

and result is correct: 275637ms

But when the string looks slightly different (amount of columns is changed) the result will not be the same.

How do I achieve same outcome but in the way that it is not dependant on the columns amount ?

Comment: for this we need you to give a [mcve]. Just one sample does not make it enough to get the idea of how this log writes

Comment: and if your number ends with `ms` always, you can make use of that... `grep -oP '\d+ms' file`

Comment: Yes it always ends with ms but this grep returns all values with ms and I need only the string which has "Brontes" word in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample input:

```
echo $ola
2016-09-05 11:23:08,022 ERROR [xxx.xxx.xx] (MSC service thread 1-6) XXXX015875: XXXX AS 7.1.1.Final Brontes started (with errors) in 275637ms - Started 1221 of 1307 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 71 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Solution using awk: Scan through each column and print the column which contains ms in it.

```
echo $ola |awk '/Brontes/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if( $i ~ /[0-9]+ms/) print $i}'
275637ms
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -oP 'Brontes.* \K\d+ms' file
```

This prints all numbers ending with `ms` from a line containing the string `Brontes` prior to that number